# Calibre: Difference between "Date" and "Published"

Tags: calibre

When editing the metadata of a book on Calibre, there are two fields that seem to have the same meaning: "Date" and "Published". What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The lookup names are pubdate (publication date) and date (calibre's "Date" column, usually the date you added the book to calibre)."

http://faq.calibrecompanion.co/index.php?action=artikel&cat=6&id=22&artlang=en

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm still curious why "date added" should be editable though...